# add height to a dynamically-created div

Tags: jquery, css, height, jquery-animate

I'm having no luck at trying to add a bit of height to a dynamically-created div.

This code gets the height of the .healcode div, which is generated dynamically and nested inside #scheduleArea, and then animates #scheduleArea to that height. I'd like to be able to add an additional 40px to whatever height is generated for .healcode.

Here's the code that works without the additional height:

```
function () { 
    $j("#scheduleArea").animate({height: $j('.healcode').css('height')}, {queue:false, duration: 1100, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) 
        },
```

The docs for the .css method call out that the "+=40" *should* give me what I'm looking for, but it zeroes out the height instead.

Ideas?

Comment: oops, didn't put in my non-working code: $j('.healcode').css('height', '+=40')},

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your issue.  You are trying to do this?

```
function () { 
    $j("#scheduleArea").animate({height: $j('.healcode').css('height','+=40')}, {queue:false, duration: 1100, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) 
},
```

If so, then the problem is that `$j('.healcode').css('height','+=40')` will increase the height of `.healcode` by 40, but then it returns the jquery object back, not the new height.  So you're trying to set the height of `#scheduleArea` to `[object]` which turns it to 0.  Try this instead:

```
function () { 
    $j("#scheduleArea").animate({height: $j('.healcode').css('height','+=40').height()}, {queue:false, duration: 1100, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) 
},
```

Note the additional call to `.height` after adding 40 to the height.

http://jsfiddle.net/CFCnZ/

NOTE: Unlike the other answers, I interpreted the question to mean you wanted to actually add the height to the `.healcode` element, not just the container.  Unsure which is correct.

Comment: you're totally correct, and it totally works. bonus points for interpreting poorly-worded question!

Answer (score 0):

```
function () { 
    $j("#scheduleArea").animate({height: $j('.healcode').css('height') + 40}, {queue:false, duration: 1100, easing: 'easeOutBounce'}) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height: ( $j('.healcode').height()) + 40 ) + 'px' ;
```

The parseInt() is required so you can perform a mathematical operation on the value.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height/ - ".height() returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400). The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation."